# Google charts line chart with non-uniform x-axis values

Tags: data-structures, charts, google-visualization, linechart

I need to make a google line chart where students answer up to five questions with a value from 1 to 100.

The line chart should have the answer on the y-axis and the time and date of the answer on the x-axis.

Students answer all questions at the same time.

There should be one line for each answer for each student.

Lines for the same question should have the same colour - ie. if there are three students there should be three lines of each colour, one for each student.

My data looks like this in PHP before it gets parsed into a json-string and loaded into Google Charts:

```
$testtable = array(
   'cols' => array(
       array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'datetime'),
       array('label' => 'Student', 'type' => 'string', 'role' => 'tooltip'),
       array('label' => 'Answer1', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'Answer2', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'Answer3', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'Answer4', 'type' => 'number'),
       array('label' => 'Answer5', 'type' => 'number')
   ),
    'rows' => array(
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Date(2014,3,4,17,3,17)'),
            array('v' => 'elev1'),
            array('v' => 15),
            array('v' => 36),
            array('v' => 87),
            array('v' => 10),
            array('v' => 22)
        )),
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Date(2014,3,4,13,56,22)'),
            array('v' => 'elev2'),
            array('v' => 11),
            array('v' => 66),
            array('v' => 87),
            array('v' => 23),
            array('v' => 27)
        )),
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Date(2014,3,5,10,27,31)'),
            array('v' => 'elev1'),
            array('v' => 43),
            array('v' => 11),
            array('v' => 33),
            array('v' => 64),
            array('v' => 88)
        )),
        array('c' => array(
            array('v' => 'Date(2014,3,5,12,22,53)'),
            array('v' => 'elev2'),
            array('v' => 22),
            array('v' => 34),
            array('v' => 62),
            array('v' => 32),
            array('v' => 5)
        )),
    )
);
```

Here is what I have in mind:
http://s21.postimg.org/p146t1dqf/chart.png

Here is what my chart currently looks like:
http://s11.postimg.org/w6gvfa5n7/chart2.png

I'm pretty sure my data is structured wrong but I can't get my head around the right way to do it. I would be really happy if someone could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A LineChart requires one data series per line, so if you want one line per student per question, you need one data series (DataTable column) per student per question (so if you have 3 students and 5 questions, you need 15 data series).  Use either the `colors` or `series.<series index>.color` options to color the lines.

```
'cols' => array(
    array('label' => 'Date', 'type' => 'datetime'),
    array('label' => 'Student1 Answer1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student1 Answer2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student1 Answer3', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student1 Answer4', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student1 Answer5', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student2 Answer1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student2 Answer2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student2 Answer3', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student2 Answer4', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student2 Answer5', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student3 Answer1', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student3 Answer2', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student3 Answer3', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student3 Answer4', 'type' => 'number'),
    array('label' => 'Student3 Answer5', 'type' => 'number')
    // etc...
)
```